# What is the unix epoch date, range [0, 253,402,300,799] in the API docs?

Tags: support, date

The type of the `fromdate` or `todate` in [several methods](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/users) is set to

> unix epoch date, range [0, 253,402,300,799]

I don't know what that is and I can't find any information -- can someone explain it or point me to the right place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are [Unix timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). They represent the number of seconds that have passed since the Unix Epoch, which occurred at 12:00 am UTC on January 1, 1970.

You can convert a human-readable date to / from a Unix timestamp using [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com). Example queries:

> "convert January 15, 2005 14:56 PST to unix timestamp"
>   "convert unix timestamp 1105829760"

The end of the range is the highest possible date represented by as a timestamp.

> convert unix timestamp 253402300799
>   Friday, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I don't understand is the `range [0, 253,402,300,799]` part. And the wikipedia article doesn't seem to say something about it..

Comment: Marked as answered, but it would be nice if you could answer to my other comment as well! thanks

Comment: I honestly don't know what that number represents. My best guess is that it represents the maximum value returned in that field.

Comment: As Nathan suggested, the end of the range is the highest possible date represented by as a timestamp. 

> convert unix timestamp 253402300799
> Friday, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT